# Lazy-loading amchart doesn't render on scroll down

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using amcharts 4.9.31 in an Angular 10 app.  I'm working on getting charts to 'lazy-load' on page scroll.
I have this setting set `am4core.options.onlyShowOnViewport = true;`
Now the charts that are outside of the viewport do not load when they are scrolled into view.  But they do when I resize the browser.  How do I get the expected behavior, i.e. that the charts render when container is scrolled into view?

Comment: Have you tried actually setting up each chart ONLY if it's container is into view? I'd try with *Intersection Observer API* to recognize whenever my container enters the screen and fire there the method that loads that specific chart.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea.  If all else fails, might go that route, but I'd prefer to use amcharts api and not have to worry about doing it myself.